Why does console.log() not display output in my Node.js program?
I am learning Node.js and trying to write a simple program. However, I noticed that when I use console.log() in a file and run it, nothing is displayed in the terminal.
Below is my code:
function sayHello(name) {
    console.log('Hello ' + name);
}

sayHello('Mosh');

Environment Information

Operating System: Windows 11
Node.js Version: v22.12.0
Editor: Latest version of VS Code


Ran the program in VS Code’s integrated terminal (PowerShell and Command Prompt):
node app.js
Result: No output displayed.
Switched to other terminals like CMD and Git Bash and ran the same code. The result was the same.
Ensured the file was saved (Ctrl + S) before running the program.
Restarted both VS Code and the terminal.
Tested with simpler code:
console.log('Hello World!');
Result: Still no output.
Used node --inspect app.js to debug but didn’t find any obvious issues.
Additional Observation:
When I manually entered the Node.js REPL mode (using the command node) and directly ran the following:
console.log('Hello');
It worked correctly, and the output was displayed as expected.

I expected the following output in the terminal:

Hello Mosh

Why is console.log() not displaying any output when running a file using node app.js, even though it works correctly in REPL mode? What could be causing this, and how can I resolve it?

I cannot reproduce this. Are you able to see the output if you run the program from the standard terminal and not VS Code's terminal? It seems no. I am able to see the output in both cases using node 22.12. There must be something not well configured. Maybe you're redirecting the output to something else or a file. I don't know if this can be done globally. Maybe start an interactive shell by typing node and then type console.log and see if any output is produced. Maybe you're calling a wrong node. Check that node's path is actually pointing to the actual node.js program.

Thank you for replying.


I also tried running the code directly in other terminals (such as PowerShell), but unfortunately, it doesn't display the result.


I accessed the interactive Node.js shell by typing node and tested it with console.log("hello"). It successfully printed "hello," but, unfortunately, running the file still doesn't work.
It's quite puzzling.



Maybe u execute this command not in right directory. Be sure, that u execute command node app.js in directory with this file.
Maybe u have other directories with files with same names, but without your console.log.
Or u execute this file from user, and your environment may have restictions to execute

Thank you for your reply.


I am certain the file location is correct.


I am curious about how to check my environment restrictions.


